# Pentaho Report Designer - Aternating blank Row when I Export my report

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

I am creating the Pentaho Report Designer reports, and I am experiencing an issue with alternating blank rows in the report. This is most noticeable when exporting to Excel or CSV format.

Is there something I need to be turning on or off to change this behaviour?

Regards

Comment: provide more clarity, if data is coming null from database you can restrict at query level ifself.

Comment: Below I try to explain better:  I created a report with Pentaho report designer that show a table.
When I export this report in Excel/CSV, the table has rows with data and rows blank alternating (the rows blank are hidden).
If I view this report by web, I cannot see the rows blank.

I would like to not have the rows blank on my table.

Comment: you have to keep all the components in continues manner, alignment should be very pixel perfect because format like Excel and CSV demands it. If it is not working out then share your .prpt file.

Comment: if you would provide us simple data sample that would greatly speed up finding answer.

Comment: I fixed my issue: I followed the suggestion of @Working Hard (every field with y=0, height=20) and I set layout=row on details section

Comment: Let me put this as a answer then @Ema , also put your comment so that it can be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to keep all the components in continues manner, alignment should be very pixel perfect because format like Excel and CSV demands it.